# non resolvable parent POM issue

Tags: maven

Hi i am having a strange issue building  a maven project on a my machine.

Their does not seem to be an issue with the pom file or code as the exact same project can be succesfully built on another workstation.

the error i receive is this

```
The project com.jonney:jon-app-parent:1.3.9 (/Users/me/Work/jon-app-paren/pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable parent POM: Failure to find com.jonney-parent:pom:3 in http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 6, column 13 -> [Help 2]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException
[ERROR] [Help 2] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/UnresolvableModelException
```

here is a snippet of my pom file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>com.jonney-parent</artifactId>
    <name>Jon SDK java</name>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.jonney</groupId>
        <artifactId>com.jonney-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.9</version>
        <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
    </parent>
```

Comment: Is that relative path (../pom.xml) valid on the new machine?

Comment: yup. this exact same codebase was working a few days ago on the machine that it no longer works now it started occuring when i cleaned/removed the  .m2 folder

Comment: First using a relative path in this case does not make sense, cause it's the default. Is this project a multi-module build? The error message `Failure to find com.jonney-parent:pom:3` bring me more into the direction that your groupId/artifactId/version combination is simply wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try calling Maven with "-U" option (force update of dependencies).